# How can I fetch all the duplicates in a pandas data frame and also index of the row which it is a copy of?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a list as follows:

```
data = [
  {"name":"John","subject":"Maths","marks":"99"},
  {"name":"John","subject":"English","marks":"95"},
  {"name":"John","subject":"Science","marks":"97"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"Maths","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"Maths","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"Science","marks":"89"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"English","marks":"92"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"Maths","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"Science","marks":"87"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"English","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"English","marks":"98"}
]
```

I have converted it to a pandas Data Frame `originalDF`

`originalDF = pd.DataFrame(data)`

```
       name  subject marks
0      John    Maths    99
1      John  English    95
2      John  Science    97
3    Robert    Maths    98
4    Robert    Maths    98 (duplicate)
5    Robert  Science    89
6    Robert  English    92
7   Lucifer    Maths    98
8   Lucifer  Science    87
9   Lucifer  English    98
10  Lucifer  English    98 (duplicate)
```

Now I was able to fetch both unique rows and duplicated rows

```
uniqueDF = originalDF.drop_duplicates()
duplicates = originalDF.duplicated()
duplicates = duplicates[duplicates == True]
duplicateDF = originalDF.loc[list(duplicates.index)]
```

Now I have both unique rows in `uniqueDF` and duplicated rows in `duplicateDF`

```
uniqueDF
      name  subject marks
0     John    Maths    99
1     John  English    95
2     John  Science    97
3   Robert    Maths    98
5   Robert  Science    89
6   Robert  English    92
7  Lucifer    Maths    98
8  Lucifer  Science    87
9  Lucifer  English    98

duplicateDF
       name  subject marks
4    Robert    Maths    98
10  Lucifer  English    98
```

Now I want to add another column `copyOf` in the `duplicateDF` which will have the index of its unique row from unique DF. I want to have the final output as follows:

```
       name  subject marks  copyof
4    Robert    Maths    98  3
10  Lucifer  English    98  9
```

Any ideas how to calculate this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for join all duplciated index values to new column with `join`:

```
c = originalDF.columns.tolist()
#filtered only duplciated rows
df = originalDF[originalDF.duplicated(keep=False)]

df = (df.rename(index=str)
        .reset_index()
        .groupby(c)
        .agg(copyof=('index',lambda x: ','.join(x[:-1])),
             orig=('index', 'last'))
        .reset_index()
        .set_index('orig'))

print (df)
         name  subject marks copyof
orig                               
10    Lucifer  English    98      9
4      Robert    Maths    98      3
```

Test for multiple values:

```
data = [
  {"name":"John","subject":"Maths","marks":"99"},
  {"name":"John","subject":"English","marks":"95"},
  {"name":"John","subject":"Science","marks":"97"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"Maths","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"Maths","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"Maths","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"Science","marks":"89"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"English","marks":"92"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"Maths","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"Science","marks":"87"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"English","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"English","marks":"98"}
]

originalDF = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (originalDF)
```

---

```
c = originalDF.columns.tolist()
df = originalDF[originalDF.duplicated(keep=False)]

df = (df.rename(index=str)
        .reset_index()
        .groupby(c)
        .agg(copyof=('index',lambda x: ','.join(x[:-1])),
             orig=('index', 'last'))
        .reset_index()
        .set_index('orig'))

print (df)
         name  subject marks copyof
orig                               
11    Lucifer  English    98     10
5      Robert    Maths    98    3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

This works although-

***Assumption:** every row will have only **one duplicate** row along with it.

```
data = [
  {"name":"John","subject":"Maths","marks":"99"},
  {"name":"John","subject":"English","marks":"95"},
  {"name":"John","subject":"Science","marks":"97"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"Maths","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"Maths","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"Science","marks":"89"},
  {"name":"Robert","subject":"English","marks":"92"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"Maths","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"Science","marks":"87"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"English","marks":"98"},
  {"name":"Lucifer","subject":"English","marks":"98"},
]

originalDF = pd.DataFrame(data)

uniqueDF = originalDF.drop_duplicates()

duplicates = originalDF.duplicated(keep=False)
duplicates = duplicates[duplicates == True]
duplicateDF = originalDF.loc[list(duplicates.index)]
duplicateDF.reset_index(inplace=True)

duplicates = list()
for i, row in duplicateDF.iterrows():
    if i % 2 == 0:
        duplicates.append(row['index'])
        
duplicateDF_ = duplicateDF[np.arange(len(duplicateDF)) % 2 != 0]
duplicateDF_['copyof'] = duplicates
```

Comment: It can have any number of duplicates.

Comment: @Inamullah the answer provided by the user - jezrael is the correct approach to this problem.